# Develop with no SIM Card

Tags: android

Can I use a device to develop on with no SIM card?
As I can't get any of my devices to show up in the run configurations. I am using Eclipse and want to test a barcode reader.
I have looked at all the info on connecting and use as debugging. I am on a mac.
But none of the devices are showing up.

When I connect a device should it be visible in the run configurations?

Comment: Yes, make sure "Debug USB" is enabled in Developer Settings

Comment: Sim cards aren't needed to develop on, unless you want to use the cellular network (you need to be on wifi to use internet without one).  More likely you either don't have USB debugging turned on on your device or you have some driver issues.

Comment: How do I check my driver issue to make sure I have the driver I am developing on a htc one

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2232799 ? Maybe this can help

Comment: If I haven't got my HTC Manager installed. Do you think thats the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use a SIM card when developing barcode Apps, all you need is just the access to Internet(sometimes the access to Internet is also not necessary, some Apps can parse the barcode locally, I think they include the parse library in the App).